# SQL Server Management Studio connects, but can't perform a select against Azure database?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I've successfully connected to an Azure hosted SQL database in SQL Server Management Studio, but I can't perform any queries that I can perform in web matrix.

The following query works just fine in web matrix:

```
SELECT *
FROM [junglegymSQL].dbo.Action AS a
```

But when I try to execute it in SQL Management Studio I receive the following error:

> Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Reference to database and/or server name in 'junglegymSQL.dbo.Action' is not supported in this
>   version of SQL Server.

Comment: Have you tried with without specifying the [junglegymSQL]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `[junglegymSQL]`  from your SQL.